# Keeping head not shaved but buzzed?

Tags: shaving

I recently started shaving my head, using an electric head razor with five blades. I've discovered that I like the look of my head with two or days' worth of hair growth, not completely shaven, but my razor only shaves down to the skin. A typical electric razor for beards seems like it would be impossible to shave my head with. What is a good option to keep my hair at this length?

Answer (score 1):

My electric hair trimmer has several plastic spacers of various sizes that clip onto it.

But when I use the hair trimmer on my beard without any spacer, it leaves about 2 mm of stubble behind. It take a little practice to get it right without pinching your skin.

It is something similar to [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/BaByliss-Men-PowerLight-Hair-Clipper/dp/B008HQ643Q/) (no affiliation).

This Amazon picture from [another product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GroomEase-Wahl-Battery-Stubble-Trimmer/dp/B071VSC8V9?th=1) shows the effect after / before.

[[image]

Comment: The 'posh' ones can do 0.4 - 10mm in 0.2mm increments or 2/3mm-28mm in 1mm. The comb is motorised. There's a beard version https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/BT5515_13/beardtrimmer-series-5000-beard-trimmer#see-all-benefits & hair version - https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/HC5630_13/hairclipper-series-5000-washable-hair-clipper#see-all-benefits [which is the one I have] I've never known a good one to bite, cheaper ones yes - they go straight in the bin ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way can be using a comb like this while shaving:

[image: comb for haircut]

Might  be more tricky to get your head shaved by yourself, but you can always ask a friend for some help.

<sup><sub>[image source](https://aliexpress.com/i/1005006026735848.html)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Remington sells a device similar to a shaver but for the head. It is available in Europe.

I have no affiliation with the product but I use it for one year and I'm pretty satisfied.

[image]